# Cloudflare data privacy and policy?

Tags: reverse-proxy, cloudflare

I am concern about cloudflare data privacy policy. On their site, it says

> Cloudflare may aggregate data we acquire about our users and the
>   visitors to their websites. For example, we may assemble data to
>   determine how Web crawlers index the Internet and whether they are
>   engaged in malicious activity.

Does it mean that they can read our data and use it, and possibly sell them to third party?  We are concern our users' data and never want the data be acquired by anyone.

If a user do a post request through https, would a reverse proxy provider like cloudflare be able to hijack our data at the proxy point?

Any advice will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CloudFlare has a certificate that decodes https, then sends requests on to your origin server, either using http or https. This isn't "hijacking our data at the proxy point", it's a feature of CloudFlare and you've authorized them to do it. They have full access to all data flowing through their server. I suggest you need to read up on [how CloudFlare works](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/205177068-Step-1-How-does-Cloudflare-work-).

The part of the privacy policy you quoted suggests they use your data in aggregate, not individually. They're PCI compliant, which suggest they've been audited and treat data appropriately.

CloudFlare run a significant portion of the internet. I think you're pretty safe, even if just by [security through obscurity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity).

Comment: You're welcome :) CloudFlare is a great system, I use it a lot myself and I put a lot of customers onto it. It really speeds websites up well.